# Difference between is DBNull & Convert.IsDBNull in C#?

Tags: c#

I am getting runtime error in c#4.5 frame work , but working well in framework 3.5 while executing the below line.

```
 if (rows[0]["GS_QUERYFIELD"] != DBNull.Value)
```

Please suggest me to which is correct or both or same with respect to the both the frameworks.

```
1) (!if (rows[0]["GS_QUERYFIELD"] is DBNull))
                 or
2) (!Convert.IsDBNUll(rows[0]["GS_QUERYFIELD"]))
```

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: This hasn't changed from one framework version to the next. What exception are you getting and where? If `rows` isn't a DataRowCollection, what is it and what does it contain?

Comment: `rows` is an instance of which class?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN documentation tells you how to do it:

```
private string AddFieldValue(string label, DataRow row, 
                         string fieldName) 
{                                
   if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(row[fieldName])) // <-- this is how you do it!
      return (string) row[fieldName] + " ";
   else 
      return String.Empty;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

So basically, *both* of your suggested approaches are incorrect, according to Microsoft's guidance.